# How can I use an Android Library module from App Engine module in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am building an android app in Android Studio and I'm using Google App Engine. Everything is working fine however I want to add some enums/classes that are common between the two projects. I've created an Android Library module and added the enums but I am having trouble adding the reference from the App Engine module. Here is my gradle for app engine:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.14'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.14'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.14'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.14'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile project(':sharedlibrary')
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

When I try to build I am then getting this error:

```
Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':backend:compile'.
```

> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.pom
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.jar
>         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.pom
>         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/appcompat-v7-21.0.3.jar
>     Required by:
>         Translink:backend:unspecified
>         Translink:backend:unspecified > Translink:sharedlibrary:unspecified

I tried adding the appcompat as a dependency but this didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java projects in Gradle can't depend on Android projects. Android projects have significantly more project state, especially in their source sets, that the Java plugin can't deal with. You're getting this specific error message becuase the Java plugin can't find the Android module's transitive dependencies because these specific dependencies require help from the Android plugin to be resolved -- the plugin is hardcoded to look for them in the SDK rather than via the repositories in the `repositories` block.

To do what you want, you'll need to refactor your common code into a plain Java module that both the Android and App Engine sides depend on.